# nullability specifier cannot be applied to non-pointer type error in Foundation?

Tags: objective-c, cmake, objective-c++

I'm trying to compile some Objective-C++ files in C++ cmake based project. I'm getting an error similar to this:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /Users/barakat/Desktop/dummy/cmake-build-debug --target dummy -- -j 2
Scanning dependencies of target dummy
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/dummy.dir/main.mm.o
In file included from /Users/barakat/Desktop/dummy/main.mm:2:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Headers/Metal.h:9:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Headers/MTLTypes.h:8:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:128:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUUID.h:26:49: error: nullability specifier '_Nullable' cannot be applied to non-pointer type 'uuid_t' (aka 'unsigned char [16]')
- (instancetype)initWithUUIDBytes:(const uuid_t _Nullable)bytes;
                                                ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSUUID.h:29:30: error: nullability specifier '_Nonnull' cannot be applied to non-pointer type 'uuid_t' (aka 'unsigned char [16]')
- (void)getUUIDBytes:(uuid_t _Nonnull)uuid;
                             ^
2 errors generated.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/dummy.dir/main.mm.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dummy.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/dummy.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [dummy] Error 2
```

This is my first time working with Objective-C/C++ but the issue appears to be in some standard header? The `uuid_t` is defined (ultimately) as `unsigned char[16]`.

Simplest code producing the error:

```
// main.mm
#import <Metal/Metal.h>
int main() {
  id <MTLDevice> device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(dummy)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
add_executable(dummy main.mm)
```

Log (Xcode? Version 8.2.1):

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /Users/barakat/Desktop/dummy
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 8.0.0.8000042
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 8.0.0.8000042
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/barakat/Desktop/dummy/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

Comment: Tried to reproduce it on Xcode 9, but it works there (excerpt for the linker phase which fails).

Comment: @AlexDenisov Thank you. I have upgraded to Xcode 9 and it compiles. Although the headers has been changed, I assume it might be compiler bug. Regarding the linker, `set_target_properties(dummy PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-framework Foundation -framework Metal")` and it fully compiles.